# Angular form is invalid when a required input is disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form input like so

```
<form name="groupForm" ng-submit="save()" ng-model="selectedItem"  novalidate>
<input 
    required 
    ng-disabled="true" 
    name="searchParameter" 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="criteria.SearchParameter" />

    <a href=""ng-click="save()" ng-class="{groupForm.$invalid}">Save All Changes</a>
```

When the value for the input is null or empty the form is invalid stating that this particular input is `required`. Is this expected or is there something I need to do?

Comment: You have `required` on the input? Therefore it is. Am I missing something?

Comment: But if it is `required` and `disabled` I would assume it is not then required?

Comment: No, `required` and `disabled` means it is required, but the user can't enter it.

Comment: I don't think they're exclusively linked tbh - I see what you mean but don't think it works like that

Comment: have a look at `ng-required` - you might be able to check if it's disabled which will let you decide whether it's required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-required`, and set a condition there:

```
<input 
     ng-required ="false"
     ng-disabled="true" 
     name="searchParameter" 
     type="text" 
     ng-model="criteria.SearchParameter" />
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfcokpqL/).

Answer (score 0):

You have the tag `required` in your `input` tag. That makes it required. In addition, you have `ng-disabled="true"` which means that you will never be able to fill in the input.

It seems like you have a misunderstand of what disabled does. Disabled just means you cant place input into it, not that it doesn't affect the form.

You are actually misusing disabled in 2 ways:

1. Disabled and required together doesn't make sense (hence your problem)
2. Specifically using the `ng-disabled="true"` also makes no sense. The advantage of `ng-disabled` is that it can be easily programaticly changed. Right now you are just hard-coding it. Might as well just use vanilla `disabled`

If you want the input to be required only when its enabled, and not required when its disabled, you can bind the two attributed to the same model:

```
<input 
    ng-required="foo"
    ng-disabled="foo" 
    name="searchParameter" 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="criteria.SearchParameter" />
```

Comment: How do I make it required only when it is enabled then?

Comment: I have a condition in there, but for the sakes of making the example simple, and removing doubt from the equation, I set it to `false`

Comment: This seems really counter-intuitive to me. Thanks though

Comment: @Chris You can use `ng-required` and bind it to the same model as `ng-disabled`. Ill update my answer with an example.